# dropdown menu not working in safari

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, navigation

can't seem to find what the problem is. firefox works fine - but safari doesn't.
a simple css dropdown menu but in safari the dropdown drops down but as soon as you try to place the mouse on the dropped down element it goes away - only if you move your mouse extremly fast on the dropped down element it doesn't hide.

http://singknaben-v2.marknolan.ch

hover your mouse "DER CHOR" and try to navigate on a child element with safari.
i can't see what the problem is. any help appriciated...

thanks,
mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the element is not tall enough. The mouse stops hovering over the element before it can reach the subelements. It can be quite simply fixed by applying a "height" css style of around 30px.